# HTML email not rendering when sent

Tags: php

my html email welcome.tpl file is formatted corrected I tested it with [PutsMail](http://putsmail.com/) and it the code below process and sends out the email but the HTML is not rendered. All i'm getting is the actually html source code in the email.

```
$mime_boundary = 'Multipart_Boundary_x'.md5(time()).'x';        
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=" .$mime_boundary. "\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$headers.= "From: <support@system.com>" . "\r\n";
$headers.= "X-Sender-IP: $_SERVER[SERVER_ADDR]" . "\r\n";
$headers.= "Date: ".date('n/d/Y g:i A') . "\r\n";
$headers.= "Reply-To: my" . "\r\n";

$subject='New Reg';

$body.= "{$mime_boundary}\n";
$body.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-2\n";
$body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$body.= $html_content;
$body.= "\n\n";
$body.= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

$html_content = file_get_contents('emails/welcome.tpl');
$body = str_replace("{Username}",$en['user'],$html_content);
mail($en['email'], $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use and check:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

All boundaries need "--" prepended, also the last (closing) mime boundary needs "--" appended, so

```
$body.= "[--]{$mime_boundary}\n";
```

should by changed to

```
$body.= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
```

on last occurrence and to

```
$body.= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
```

on all but last occurrences.

Comment: is this correct?
`$body = "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
 $body.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=charset=us-ascii\n";
 $body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
 $body.= $text_content;
 $body.= "\n\n";
 $body.= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
  
 $body.= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
        $body.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-\n";
 $body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
 $body.= $html_content;
 $body.= "\n\n";
 $body.= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";`

Comment: other way round: start with $body = "--{$mime_boundary}\n"; end with $body.= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";